Brick netcdf of 5 dimensions in R
I used to use the next function with a netcdf of 4 dimensions (longitude, latitude, time, and member) and using brick and could reduce the netcdf to 3 dimensions (long, lat, time), however the product was updated to a version with 5 dimensiones (longitude, latitude, time, version and member). In this case, my function is not working any more with the new version. Does anyone know how to solve it please?
var='tp'
fecha='2024-09-01'
nombre_archivo<-paste0('resample/',var,'_',fecha,'_res.Rdata')

ff_resample<- function(var,rast_base,fecha,m_fcst){
  setwd(paste0(dir_base,'/Descarga de pronosticos'))
  nombre_archivo<-paste0('resample/',var,'_',fecha,'_res.Rdata')
  if(file.exists(nombre_archivo)){
    load(nombre_archivo)
    print('Ya existe. Cargando...')
    return(array)
  }else{
    print('resampleando')
    array <-  array(NA,dim=c(dim(rast_base)[1],dim(rast_base)[2],m_fcst, 215)) ##precipitaciones diarias hindcast [mes pronostico, lon, lat,miembro,lead-time]
    nombre_nc <- paste0(var,'_',fecha,'.nc')
    for(m in 1:m_fcst){
      print(m)
      ncstack <- brick(nombre_nc,varname=var,level=1)
      res     <- resample(ncstack,rast_base,method='bilinear')
      if(var=='tp'){
        res2<-as.array(res)*1000
        res3<-res2
        for (lt in 2:215){
          res3[,,lt]=(res2[,,lt]-res2[,,(lt-1)])
        }
      }else{
        res2<-as.array(res)
        res3<-array(NA,dim=c(dim(rast_base)[1],dim(rast_base)[2],215))
        aux<-1
        for(lt in 1:215){
          res3[,,lt]<-apply(res2[,,aux:(aux+3)],c(1,2),mean)-273.15
          aux<-aux+4
        }
      }
      array[,,,m]<-res3
    }
   # save(array,file=paste0('resample/',var,'_',fecha,'_res.Rdata'))
    #array<-aperm(array,perm=c(1,3,2,4))
    return(array)
  }
  setwd(dir_base)
}


class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 46, 13, 598, 215  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -77.5, -64.5, -60.5, -14.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : tp_2024-09-01.nc 
names      : X24, X48, X72, X96, X120, X144, X168, X192, X216, X240, X264, X288, X312, X336, X360, ... 
forecast_period (hours): 24, 5160 (min, max)
varname    : tp 
level      : 1 

Warning message:
In .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
  tp has more than 4 dimensions, I do not know what to do with these data


To answer your question you should provide more information. What data set are you using? Can you share a sample file? Is it available online somewhere? Why do you need to resample, what are the extent and resolution of rast_base?
